# JMX RMI authentication not working

Tags: java, authentication, jmx, jconsole

I have configured my Java application to require authentication but not SSL

JVM args:

```
-Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localIpAddress
```

management.properties:

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=39998
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=39999
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

jmxremote.access

```
monitorRole readonly
dev readwrite
tester readwrite
```

jmxremote.password

```
monitorRole guest
dev dev
tester test
```

However, I am able to access this application without having to enter any credentials.

```
jconsole ipOfApplication:39998
```

I get direct access, without any password prompts.  How do I make sure that I get prompted to login?

NOTE: Even after enabling SSL, the same behavior occurs.

Comment: Any special reason for using the custom RMI Agent? IMO, the problem is caused by the agent. The out-of-the-box configuration works as expected (tested on JDK7u45, JDK8b115)

Comment: I am unable to access the JMX application without the Custom RMI agent

Comment: I suppose you need to route the JMX traffic through a firewall, right?

Comment: Yes, according to the answer in this post, by default, a wide range of ports must be opened for a remote connection to work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work

Comment: Actually, since JDK7u4 you can specify the RMI registry port - and that's the part that was causing the problems - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442719/remote-jmx-technology/19528077#19528077

Comment: I have verified that property works for me, so I don't have to use a custom agent.  However, I still face the same issue as before: access is allowed without authentication.

Comment: Could you please post the content of jmxremote.password.file, jmxremote.access.file and your JVM parameters for JMX?

Comment: I posted the requested info.

Comment: Are you running the right JVM? maybe you have more than one JVM in your OS and you are running a JVM with a wrong management.properties file, check your Java home (alternatives or PATH env variable in Windows) and edit java/jre/lib/management/management.properties file to ensure that it is ok.

Comment: I double checked that by changing the ports and trying to connect.  It is the correct file.

Comment: From docs.oracle.com " Note - The com.sun.management.jmxremote.* properties could have been specified in a management.properties file instead of passing them at the command line. In that case, the system property -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=management.properties would be required to specify the location of the management.properties file."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6002
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6003
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

and open ports 6002, 6003 on your FW for the JMX traffic. This will enable you to access JMX server remotely without introducing any custom RMI agent.

Comment: I have verified that property works for me, so I don't have to use a custom agent.  However, I still face the same issue as before: access is allowed without authentication.  I want to make sure all access is authenticated.